# Why is Django FieldFIle readline() returning the hex version of a text file?

Tags: python, django, boto, readline

Having an odd problem.

I have a Django app that opens a file (represented as a Django `FieldFile`) and reads each row using `readline()` as below:

```
with file.open(mode='r') as f:
  row = f.readline()
  # do something with row...
```

The file is text, utf-8 encoded and lines are terminated with `\r\n`.

The problem is each row is being read as the hex representation of the string, so instead of "Hello" I get "48656c6c6f".

A few stranger things:

- It previously worked properly, but at some point an update has broken it (I've tried rolling back to previous commits and it is still wonky, so possibly a dependency has updated and not something from my `requirements.txt`). Missed it in my testing because it is in a very rarely used part of the app.
- If I read the same file using `readlines()` instead of `readline()` I see the correct string representation of the file wrapped in `[b'...']`
- The file reads normally if I do it using straight Python `open()` and `readline()` from an interpreter
- Forcing text mode with `mode='rt'` doesn't change the behaviour, neither does `mode='rb'`
- The file is stored in a Minio bucket, so the defaut storage is `storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage` from `django-storages` and not the default Django storage class. This means that `boto3`, `botocore` and `s3fs` are also in the mix, making it more confusing for me to debug.

Scratching my head at why this worked before and what I'm doing wrong.

Environment is Python 3.8, Django 2.2.8 and 3.0 (same result) running in Docker containers.

**EDIT**

Let me point out that the fix for this is simply using

```
row = f.readline().decode()
```

but I would still like to figure out what's happening.

**EDIT 2**

Further to this, FieldFile.open() is reading the file as a binary file, whereas plain Python open() is reading the file as a text file.

Answer (score 1):

This seems very weird. 
I think you will see the solution immediately after trying following (I will then update my answer or delete it if it really doesn't help to find it, but I'm quite confident)

A assume, that there is some code, that is monkeypatching file.open or the django view function.

What I suggest is:

Start your code with manage.py runserver
Ad following code to manage.py (as the ***very first lines***)

```
import file
print("ID of file.open at manage startup is", id(file.open)
```

Then add code to your view directly one line above the `file.open`

```
    print("ID of file.open before opening is", id(file.open)
```

If both ids are different, then something monkeypatched your open function.
If both are the same, then the problem must be somewhere else.

If you don not see the output of these two prints, something might have monkeypatched your view.

If this doesn't work, then try to use
`open()` instead of `file.open()`

Is there any particular reason you use `file.open()`

**Addendum 1:**

So what you sai is, that file is an object instance of a class is it a FileField? 
In any case can you obtain the name of the file and open it with a normal `open()` to see whether it is only `file.open()` that does funny things or whether it is also `open()` reading it this stange way.
Did you just open the file from command line with `cat filename` (or if under windows with `type filename`?

If that doesn't work we could add traces to follow each line of the source code that is being executed.

**Addendum 2:**

Well if you can't try this in a `manage.py runserver`, what happens if you try to read the file with a `manage.py shell`?

Just open the shell and type something like:

```
from <your_application>.models import <YourModel>
entry = <YourModel>.objects.get(id=<idofentry>)
line1 = entry.<filefieldname>.open("r").read().split("\n")[0]
print("line1 = %r" % line1)
```

If this is still not conclusive, (but only if you can reproduce the issue with the management shell, then create a small file containing the lines.

```
from <your_application>.models import <YourModel>
entry = <YourModel>.objects.get(id=<idofentry>)
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
line1 = entry.<filefieldname>.open("r").read().split("\n")[0]
print("line1 = %r" % line1)
```

And import it from the management shell.
The code should enter the debugger and now you can single step through the open function and see whether you end up on sime weird function in some monkeypatch.

Comment: I suspect you're correct and that somewhere in that chain of storage managers it is monkeypatched. Going to try this now.

Comment: Just to clarify, `file` is the variable referring to an instance of `FieldFile`, so it could just as easily be `x.open()`

Comment: So upon further examination, I think this is the right direction but the wrong way to diagnose. The app is run by uWSGI in both production and dev environments- we don't use `runserver` because it can't set up the necessary environment and dependencies. Also `file.open()` is the `open()' method being called on the object `file` - not sure if the id stays the same, and in any event, `file` doesn't exist when the app is instantiated.

Comment: further enhanced the answer

Comment: Re. Addendum 1 - yes tried this (see bullet point 3 in my post) and it cats fine, etc.

Comment: Re. Addendum 2 - the debugger steps through the expected Django code then gets into frozen libraries, which are beyond my debugging skill to really follow, so I'm just going to have to go with my solution above unless someone has familiarity with the specific libraries I'm using.

Comment: Yeah that's weird. So my answer is not really helpful and I'm running out of ideas.
As you mentioned your file objects are not real file objects, but some file like objects (boto3...) So I think it's not that easy to find the root cause, except you manage to create a smallest possible setup which still reproduces the behavior and that you can show, what to remove/change (e.g. boto3) to no more have that behavior.

Just not sure its worth the effort if you have a solution

Comment: Thanks and I think you’re correct but I appreciate the suggestions - learned a few new tricks from my debugging!